# Problem installing Devel module onto site

Tags: 8, installation

I went to drupal.org, copied the link for the Devel module, went to my site, New Module (under extensions) paste the link into the "Install from a URL" and when I hit Install it gives me the following error message: "Failed to fetch file due to error "cURL error 77: SSL: can't load CA certificate file /Applications/DevDesktop/common/cert/cacert.pem (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)"
Unable to retrieve Drupal project from https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/devel-8.x-1.0-rc1.tar.gz."

How can I fix this?

Comment: You can get around it for now by downloading directly from drupal.org, opening the file and placing the contents in /modules.

Answer (score 1):

Download [this file](https://curl.se/ca/cacert.pem) and save it on the desktop.

Then copy (or move) it into the `C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop\common\cert\` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the server work for me

you might want to consider just restarting apache server only

otherwise you might have to follow the solution here https://www.drupal.org/node/2481341

```
- Download latest cacert.pem from http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html.
- On global PHP level add curl.cainfo = [enter your path]\cacert.pem to your php.ini.
- Restart Apache service.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Acquia's Dev Desktop, copying the libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll and libssl-1_1-x64.dll from the PHP7.3 folder to the Apache/bin folder resolved the issue for me.

"Beginning with version 1.1.0 OpenSSL did change their libary names! libeay32.dll is now libcrypto-.dll (e.g. libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll for OpenSSL 1.1.x on 64bit windows) ssleay32.dll is now libssl-.dll (e.g. libssl-1_1-x64.dll for OpenSSL 1.1.x on 64bit windows)"

epos_jk
See https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php#121921.